# Android video mirror effect

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-textureview

I'm working on a camera application that has to capture video in mirror effect. I used texture view to show video preview with mirror effect. Now video preview showing mirror effect but after video being captured and saved it don't have mirror effect.

I used MediaRecorder to save video file.

I Google this problem but didn't find any solution.
[image: Mirror effect is showing in camera preview]

[image: But after saving video mirror effect not showing]

I want to save video with mirror effect as shown in camera preview.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you let me know when you're applying matrix transform method? As I'm doing and getting black display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem by flipping the video.
when the video is completed I'm storing the original video temporary and then applying the flip effect and got the mirror effect in video.

[Flip video library](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android/blob/master/README.md)